# Unable to delete files from the list using Remove-Item in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete a list of files which is stored as InputObject names from a variable, '$exclude_files', using Remove-Item cmdlet.

Since it is a list, I am iterating through the list and getting the InputObject file names.

Below is the code:

```bsh
$source_dir ="C:\Files"

#Files are in below variable $exclude_files

$exclude_files

InputObject      SideIndicator
-----------      -------------
Credentials.xml  =>
EC2_Ubuntu.pem   =>
file2.png        =>
file3.txt        =>
Terminals.config =>

# tried with giving path and without giving path
foreach ($i in $exclude_files){ Remove-Item -Path $source_dir  $i.InputObject }
```

But, I am getting the following error:

> Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Files\file3.txt' because it does
>   not exist. At line:1 char:31
>   + foreach($i in $exclude_files){Remove-Item $i.InputObject}
>   +                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Files...file3.txt:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: If the script throws error only for 'file3.txt', please check if the file exists in the source directory.

Comment: Probably you should use something like, 
`foreach ($i in $exclude_files){ Remove-Item -Path ($source_dir  + "\" + $i.InputObject) }`

Comment: Please have the code match the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution for that.. as you suggested, when  iterate through the list with the InputObject, its working

```bsh
foreach($i in $exclude_files)
            {
                $i.InputObject | Remove-Item -Path {Join-Path $source_dir $_}
    }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$exclude_files.InputObject | Remove-Item -Path {Join-Path $source_dir $_ }
```

It seems that `$i.InputObject` is used as input for the `-Filter` parameter (since this is the first positional parameter in the `Path` parameter set), which might not be the intended idea.

Comment: Hi @Moerwald . This not working . Iam getting following error
Remove-Item : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:17
+ $exclude_files| Remove-Item -Path {Join-Path $source_dir $_ }
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Files\...deIndicator==>}:String) [Remove-Item], ArgumentException

Comment: You might have an easier time if you strip the `Compare-Object` formatting off first. I would use `$exclude_files = $exclude_files | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject`

Comment: @HariUmesch if my answer is fine for you, mark it as correct one (Check Mark). Thx